# Convert structure to PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, data-conversion

The horrible system we use in my company gives me the following output:

```
{
    party:"bases",
    number:"1",
    id:"xx_3039366",
    url:"systen01-ny.com",
    target:"_self",
    address:"Ch\u00e3o as Alminhas-Medas,Uteiros de Gatos e Fontes Longaq<br/>64320-761 ANHADOS LdA",
    coordinate:{
        x:90.995262145996094,
        y:-1.3394836426
    },
    contactDetails:{
        id:"366",
        phone:"xxxxxx",
        mobile:"",
        fax:"xxxx 777 235",
        c2c:!0
    },
    parameters:"Flex Am\u00e1vel Silva,hal,,EN_30336,S,786657,1,0,",
    text:"Vila Nova de Loz C\u00f4a,os melhores vinhos, v\u00e1rias. Produtor/exportador/com\u00e9rcio",
    website:null,
    mail:"",
    listing:"paid",
    pCode:"64",
    name:"xpto Am\u00e1vel Costa",
    logo:{src:"http://ny.test.gif",
    altname:"xpto Am\u00e1vel Costa"},
    bookingUrl:"",
    ipUrl:"",
    ipLabel:"",
    customerId:"7657",
    addressId:"98760",
    combined:null,
    showReviews:!0
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to convert the output to array, as if it were a json, or even some other format that I can manipulate this data in PHP. Json_decode does not work.

Comment: it's true that it's not valid json, wont be trivial I can tell you that.

Comment: This is not JSON, its a javascript object literal. If you can JSON stringify it on the front end...if not then good luck

Comment: any more information?

Comment: @MatthewBrent - interesting idea! it might work.

Comment: I could write a parser for it using my handy dandy Parser/Lexer Tokenizer but It would take quite a bit of work. ( aka. I'm to lazy to do it  )

Comment: Is this an entire example or would you be parsing multiple blocks like this at one time, it may be possible to simple wrap some of this in `"` and make it readable.

Comment: If you can't rely on the client-side processing or PHP parsing, you could also use a Javascript interpreter to execute and return the JSON stringify on the server side. Something like Node.JS or use a library like [js4php5](https://github.com/hiltonjanfield/js4php5). `$json = JS:run('var output = JSON.stringify('. $data. '); print(output);');`

Comment: Ok, I lied maybe I'll write you one, it will take me some time though, dinner right now, too ... check back later.

Comment: what's this supposed to be `\u00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like I said I would, here your very own Json Object parser.

One word of warning, these kind of things can be more art then science so if your inputs vary from what was in your example, it could have issues.  Given the small sample size (1 document) I make no guarantees on it's functionality outside that one example.

I would try to explain how this works, but I fear it would be lost on mere mortals.

Seriously, this was fun, enjoyed the challenge for once.

```
<?php
function parseJson($subject, $tokens)
{
    $types = array_keys($tokens);
    $patterns = [];
    $lexer_stream = [];

    $result = false;

    foreach ($tokens as $k=>$v){
        $patterns[] = "(?P<$k>$v)";      
    } 
    $pattern = "/".implode('|', $patterns)."/i";

    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        //print_r($matches);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
            $match = [];
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $match = $matches[$type][$key];
                if (is_array($match) && $match[1] != -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            $tok  = [
                'content' => $match[0],
                'type' => $type,
                'offset' => $match[1]
            ];

            $lexer_stream[] = $tok;       
        }

       $result = parseJsonTokens( $lexer_stream );
    }
    return $result;
} 

function parseJsonTokens( array &$lexer_stream ){

    $result = [];

    next($lexer_stream); //advnace one
    $mode = 'key'; //items start in key mode  ( key => value )

    $key = '';
    $value = '';

    while($current = current($lexer_stream)){
        $content = $current['content'];
        $type = $current['type'];

        switch($type){
            case 'T_WHITESPACE'://ignore whitespace
                next($lexer_stream);
            break;
            case 'T_STRING':
                //keys are always strings, but strings are not always keys
                if( $mode == 'key')
                    $key .= $content;
                else
                    $value .= $content;           
                next($lexer_stream); //consume a token
            break;
            case 'T_COLON':
                $mode = 'value'; //change mode key :
                next($lexer_stream);//consume a token
            break;
            case 'T_ENCAP_STRING':
                $value .= trim(unicode_decode($content),'"'); //encapsulated strings are always content
                next($lexer_stream);//consume a token
            break;   
            case 'T_NULL':
                 $value = null; //encapsulated strings are always content
                 next($lexer_stream);//consume a token
            break;          
            case 'T_COMMA':  //comma ends an item               
                //store
                $result[$key] = $value;
                //reset
                $mode = 'key'; //items start in key mode  ( key => value ) 
                $key = '';
                $value = ''; 
                next($lexer_stream);//consume a token
            break;
            case 'T_OPEN_BRACE': //start of a sub-block
                $value = parseJsonTokens($lexer_stream); //recursive
            break;
            case 'T_CLOSE_BRACE': //start of a sub-block
                //store
                $result[$key] = $value;
                next($lexer_stream);//consume a token
                return $result;
            break;
            default:
                print_r($current);
                trigger_error("Unknown token $type value $content", E_USER_ERROR);
        }

    }

    if( !$current ) return;   
    print_r($current);
    trigger_error("Unclosed item $mode for $type value $content", E_USER_ERROR);
}

//@see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha
function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}

function unicode_decode($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $str);
}

$str = '{
    party:"bases",
    number:"1",
    id:"xx_3039366",
    url:"systen01-ny.com",
    target:"_self",
    address:"Ch\u00e3o as Alminhas-Medas,Uteiros de Gatos e Fontes Longaq<br/>64320-761 ANHADOS LdA",
    coordinate:{
        x:90.995262145996094,
        y:-1.3394836426
    },
    contactDetails:{
        id:"366",
        phone:"xxxxxx",
        mobile:"",
        fax:"xxxx 777 235",
        c2c:!0
    },
    parameters:"Flex Am\u00e1vel Silva,hal,,EN_30336,S,786657,1,0,",
    text:"Vila Nova de Loz C\u00f4a,os melhores vinhos, v\u00e1rias. Produtor/exportador/com\u00e9rcio",
    website:null,
    mail:"",
    listing:"paid",
    pCode:"64",
    name:"xpto Am\u00e1vel Costa",
    logo:{src:"http://ny.test.gif",
    altname:"xpto Am\u00e1vel Costa"},
    bookingUrl:"",
    ipUrl:"",
    ipLabel:"",
    customerId:"7657",
    addressId:"98760",
    combined:null,
    showReviews:!0
}';

$tokens = [
    'T_OPEN_BRACE'      => '\{',
    'T_CLOSE_BRACE'     => '\}',
    'T_NULL'            => '\bnull\b',
    'T_ENCAP_STRING'    => '\".*?(?<!\\\\)\"',
    'T_COLON'           => ':',
    'T_COMMA'           => ',',
    'T_STRING'          => '[-a-z0-9_.!]+',
    'T_WHITESPACE'      => '[\r\n\s\t]+',
    'T_UNKNOWN'         => '.+?'
];

var_export( parseJson($str, $tokens) );
```

Outputs ( this is what everyone wants )

```
array (
  'party' => 'bases',
  'number' => '1',
  'id' => 'xx_3039366',
  'url' => 'systen01-ny.com',
  'target' => '_self',
  'address' => 'Chão as Alminhas-Medas,Uteiros de Gatos e Fontes Longaq<br/>64320-761 ANHADOS LdA',
  'coordinate' => 
  array (
    'x' => '90.995262145996094',
    'y' => '-1.3394836426',
  ),
  'contactDetails' => 
  array (
    'id' => '366',
    'phone' => 'xxxxxx',
    'mobile' => '',
    'fax' => 'xxxx 777 235',
    'c2c' => '!0',
  ),
  'parameters' => 'Flex Amável Silva,hal,,EN_30336,S,786657,1,0,',
  'text' => 'Vila Nova de Loz Côa,os melhores vinhos, várias. Produtor/exportador/comércio',
  'website' => NULL,
  'mail' => '',
  'listing' => 'paid',
  'pCode' => '64',
  'name' => 'xpto Amável Costa',
  'logo' => 
  array (
    'src' => 'http://ny.test.gif',
    'altname' => 'xpto Amável Costa',
  ),
  'bookingUrl' => '',
  'ipUrl' => '',
  'ipLabel' => '',
  'customerId' => '7657',
  'addressId' => '98760',
  'combined' => NULL,
  'showReviews' => '!0',
)
```

And you can even test it here ( because I am a nice guy )

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c1dcafb59abbf19f7f3209724dbdd4a46546c57

I was able to fix the encoding issues `\u00e` etc with help of this SO post, so a shout out to them, because I hate character encoding.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char

Man I just love a beautiful piece of code, just umm.

Cheers!

Comment: You deserve like 10 upvotes for your enthusiasm, and another 50 for actually writing out a full json parser. Good job and thank you for not being the typical SO a**hole

Comment: I been doing a lot with parsers right now, so I had most the code, or at least the hard bits already worked out.  I am writing a HTML template parser for doing templates and compiling them into PHP code.  Next to that this was fairly easy, still fun though.

Comment: Dude, I really can not believe you solved the problem. I had begun to write this analyzer, but it would take another two days to get ready. Posting here was my last alternative, did not imagine that someone would respond with such a direct solution. It tested and worked with all the outputs provided by the system. Saved my day.

Comment: only took just over 2 hours, and i was watching walking dead . lol .  sure thing glad I could help.