# PHP - JSON Decode Unicode Emoji Characters in a String

Tags: php, json, regex, unicode

I know it's a stupid question but I am done experimenting and wasting further time on it. To cut the story short here's what I am battling with:

I have a string `$userName = "John \uD83D\uDE0D\uD83D\uDE0D\uD83D\uDE0D";`

I have to apply `json_decode()` on all unicode occurrences in this string like `\uD83D`, `\uDE0D`, `\uDE0D` etc.

I thought I could use some regex based solution. Can you help me get this done.

Comment: can you clarify your question? Why should you use json decode on a string?

Comment: I have to send this string as a push notification to iphone users. And I have to convert those emojis to their symbols.

Comment: May be I don't have to use json_decode. Can you propose any other solutions?

Comment: that's ok. I don't get where the json part comes in...

Comment: Where did you get the string from in the first place? Was it proper JSON at some point?

Comment: that string is the username (along with emojis) stored in mysql database.

Comment: it's simply a varchar data type and has exactly the same string value as written in the question above

Comment: And how did it sprout its unicode escape sequences?

Comment: Users get themselves registered through iphone app, and they can add emojis to their names. That's how these unicode characters get in to the database.

Comment: You need to fix something in that registration process then. The database should store the raw emoji Unicode characters, not their escape sequences.

Comment: Right, but that's not in my hand now. I just have to fix this. When I did `json_decode("\uD83D")` then I get the proper emoji in push notification.

Comment: Well, see the duplicate. This'll do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975110/476

Comment: Great, that did the trick. Thanks a lot deceze.

Comment: Actually I already tried accepted answer, it didn't work. This time I tried masakielastic's answer and it worked like a charm. Thanks for pointing me to it again.