# Decode UTF-8 escaped string

Tags: php, utf-8

I have searched all around the internet for a solution for my specific issue, but to no avail.

I'm trying to decode the following string:

```
\x3cdiv\x3e\x3cdiv style\x3d\x22padding-bottom:12px;padding-top:0px\x22 class\x3d\x22hwc kCrYT\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22yStFkb\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22Gx5Zad xpd EtOod pkphOe\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22kCrYT\x22\x3e\x3cdiv\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd\x22\x3e\x3cdiv\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd\x22\x3eLG Optimus One P500 price in India starts from \x3cspan class\x3d\x22FCUp0c rQMQod\x22\x3e\u20b95,299\x3c/span\x3e.\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22x54gtf\x22\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22kCrYT\x22\x3e\x3ca href\x3d\x22/url?q\x3dhttps://www.smartprix.com/mobiles/lg-optimus-one-p500-p133\x26amp;sa\x3dU\x26amp;ved\x3d2ahUKEwiXhre6zdCCAxUrkmoFHcPEARoQFnoECAMQBg\x26amp;usg\x3dAOvVaw2IXtrxhIz2KypXQY1-VkOj\x22 data-ved\x3d\x222ahUKEwiXhre6zdCCAxUrkmoFHcPEARoQFnoECAMQBg\x22\x3e\x3cspan\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd UwRFLe\x22 style\x3d\x22-webkit-line-clamp:2\x22\x3e\x3cspan class\x3d\x22rQMQod Xb5VRe\x22\x3eLG Optimus One P500 Price in India 2023, Full Specs \x26amp; Review | Smartprix\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd UwRFLe\x22 style\x3d\x22-webkit-line-clamp:2\x22\x3ewww.smartprix.com \u203a mobiles \u203a lg-opti...\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22P1NWSe\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22wOMIed nkPlDb\x22\x3e\x3cspan class\x3d\x22JhFlyf VQFmSd\x22\x3e\x3ca class\x3d\x22f4J0H\x22 href\x3d\x22https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv\x3d583654954\x26amp;sxsrf\x3dAM9HkKmiEu1JuU2lrgOfiWibXbICyQENmA:1700415524431\x26amp;ei\x3dJEhaZZfkGaukqtsPw4mH0AE\x26amp;q\x3dWhat+is+the+price+of+LG+P500?\x26amp;sa\x3dX\x26amp;ved\x3d2ahUKEwiXhre6zdCCAxUrkmoFHcPEARoQzmd6BAgDEAc\x22 data-ved\x3d\x222ahUKEwiXhre6zdCCAxUrkmoFHcPEARoQzmd6BAgDEAc\x22\x3eMore results\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e
```

Using `stripcslashes` does the job, but the `₹` sign is not being decoded properly.

Another more concise example would be this:

```
320\xd7480
```

Where it should decode to `320×480`, but returns `320�480`.

Any tips?

Comment: `0xD7` is in the extended range of ASCII, so your best bet is to convert to UTF-8 and specify which original encoding you were using: https://3v4l.org/L8bNl

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have tried both separately, but not together, thanks

Comment: @ChrisHaas the rupee sign is still giving me issues. I will keep trying on my own and update the question once I find a solution

Comment: It is possible that I picked the wrong code page to convert from. What is the hex sequence that you expect to result in `₹`

Comment: This works for your example - https://3v4l.org/2I1jT. There are some other possible solutions in the answers to this - [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563)

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks everyone for the help. I will publish an answer soon that uses `json_decode`. The answer @user1191247 linked doesn't work against the second example.

Comment: @lolc forget my prior comment about UTF16, that was based on my misreading of user1191247 code and how it converts `\uxxxx` escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it

This replaces `\x00` and `\u0000` characters.

```php
$answer =
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/\\\u[A-f0-9]{4}|\\\x[A-f0-9]{2}/',
        function($match){

            if($match[0][1] == "u"){
                            
                return json_decode('"' . $match[0] . '"');
            }else{
                            
                return mb_convert_encoding(
                    stripcslashes($match[0]),
                    "utf-8",
                    "windows-1252"
                );
            }
        },
        $accdefs_regex[2][$i]
    );
```

Comment: `[A-f]` is not a range of `[A-Fa-f]`.

Comment: Some adjustments https://3v4l.org/4AfcQ

Comment: On second look at these it seems like the input data is a mix of two different encodings as well as escaping conventions. Whatever is _upstream_ of this code producing the problematic data should be fixed so as to avoid this and similar issues.

Comment: @Sammitch this code is used as a part of my google scraper, I can't really fix that problem.