# What is this character format and how to decode to normal text?

Tags: javascript, php, format, character, smf-forum

this is the result of a post with normal text after hit the edit button, on a forum webpage where I am admin.

%u0398%u03B1 %u03C4%u03C1%u03B5%u03BE%u03C9 %u03B5%u03C3%u03C4%u03C9 %u03BA%u03B1%u03B9 %u03BC%u03B5 %u03B5%u03BD%u03B1 %u03C0%u03BF%u03B4%u03B9

How to get the original normal text?

A little research I did showed that the forum(Simple Machine Forum) is built with javascript and php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934602/1427878 has a way to do this for the `\uXXYY` format; you got a `%` instead of `\\` here, but the regular expression used to find those sequences, should not be that hard to modify.

Comment: @CBroe the text is greek, do the method you mention on link work with greek?

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase Php problem

Comment: If this is a JS or PHP problem, please share the code involved. Are you using any self-written code for this, or are you facing a problem when using SMF without any modifications? Also, please add all clarification to your question, not to the comment section

Comment: What human language the content is in, has little to do with this. https://3v4l.org/ECZFH - looks pretty Greek to me, so what actual issue are you having with this, that made you ask regarding the language ...?

Comment: @CBroe perfect, just didn't understand how your method work...
Thanks any way