# Latin Character Rendering PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a mysql table it have a  field which data contains latin description with some latin characters it stores like below

```
BBVA Bancomer   0445574935<br\/>Banamex   19582 Sucursal 4346<br><br\/><br\/>Ambas cuentas a nombre de Shaklee M\u00e9xico, S. de RL. de CV.<br\/><br\/>Para adjuntar su ficha de pago y\/o formas de registro de clic aqu\u00ed <a href=\"index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=form&formid=8\">REPORTA AQU\u00cd TU PAGO Y\/O FORMA DE REGISTRO<\/a>
```

i need to send this description via email, but i select using mysql query it getting same as above, i need to render lathin characters like below

```
BBVA Bancomer 0445574935
Banamex 19582 Sucursal 4346


Ambas cuentas a nombre de Shaklee México, S. de RL. de CV.

Para adjuntar su ficha de pago y/o formas de registro de clic aquí REPORTA AQUÍ TU PAGO Y/O FORMA DE REGISTRO
```

Ex - M\u00e9xico = México
Please let me know is there any solution with PHP to render those kind of text to latin
thank you

Comment: You're storing the data as (almost) html. That means you either need to send an html email or store the data properly, (That is, store the raw data not the HTML. This would allow you to change the presentation depending on where you want to use it by adding HTML/other formatting when displaying)

Comment: i can render this on page correctly but in email it shows as this (i used strislashed for remove \ before)

Ambas cuentas a nombre de Shaklee Mu00e9xico, S. de RL. de CV.

Para adjuntar su ficha de pago y/o formas de registro de clic aquu00ed REPORTA AQUu00cd TU PAGO Y/O FORMA DE REGISTRO

Comment: Have a look at this example of sending HTML email: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=416467

Comment: No Im looking for convert 
M\u00e9xico kind of word to  México , this will solve my problem surely

Comment: for the \u see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045058/converting-these-types-of-unicode-to-utf8-in-php